# Eloquent: Query the length of field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to do something like that in Laravel (valid sqlite query):

```
select * from 'tbUsers' where  length(name)>50;
```

I tried

```
User::with('Permissons')->where('LENGTH(name)','>','50')->get();
```

But it seems not to work........

**note**: other queries works without problem:

```
User::with('Permissons')->where('active','=','1')->get();
```

Comment: If you don't necessarily want to stick to Eloquent, you can use "Raw queries" https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this 
`whereRaw( string $sql, array $bindings = array(), string $boolean = 'and')`

```
User::with('Permissons')->whereRaw('LENGTH(name) > 50')->get();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `whereRaw`:

```
User::with('Permissons')->whereRaw('LENGTH(name) > ?', [50])->get();
```

Comment: I don't understand the reason but your solution doesn't work for me. I'm using the solution provided by @vijaykumar.

Comment: I think this one, with bound variables, is more correct.

Comment: @iateadonut it is more secure if you allow user input. With a literal, hard-coded value they are equally correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your test you tried `'LENGTH(name)'`, but this converts to a string which means the select statement becomes more like:

```
select * from 'tbUsers' where 'LENGTH(name)' > 50;
```

Which is bad. In order to stop treating it as a string you need to let where() know what you're entering is raw-sql, to do that you can use `DB::raw`:

```
User::with('Permissons')->where(DB::raw('LENGTH(name)'),'>','50')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple `LENGTH(name)` use `char_length(name)` to get length of characters in string. `LENGTH()`  returns the length of the string measured in bytes. `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in characters.

For Example:

```
LENGTH('déjà vu')  => 9
CHAR_LENGTH('déjà vu') => 7
```